# How to force WebApi Help Page to show parent controller?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, api, asp.net-web-api

I have 3 controllers:

- ParentController
- ChildOneController (inherits ParentController)
- ChildTwoController (inherits ParentController)

When I use the WebApi Help Page, only ChildOne and ChildTwo show up in the help page, but not Parent controller. Why? How can I have the ParentController show up in the help page?

Comment: What version are you targeting?  I just did this with .NET 4.5 using Visual Studio 2013 (Preview) and it works.

Comment: VS 2012 with .NET 4.5. One of the routes was hidding the parent controller. Thanks @RickRainey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After changing the routes a bit, I got to see them all. It appears one of my routes was hiding the parent controller.